# Eigenspaces and covering relations of twisted involutions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetric-spaces, involutions

Let $\theta:G\to G$ be an involution of a complex connected reductive Lie group, preserving a maximal torus $T$ (which, for me, lies inside a $\theta$-invariant Borel $B$). Let $K = G^\theta$ be the fixed points, a "symmetric subgroup".

The **twisted involutions** in $W := N_G(T)/T$ are $\{w \in W\ :\ \theta\cdot w = w^{-1} \}$. Equivalently, $w$ is a twisted involution if $w\theta$ is an involution of $T$. Let $E_-(w) \leq {\mathfrak t}^*$ be the $-1$ eigenspace of $w\theta$ (following the notation of Richardson-Springer).

Let $w \gtrdot v$ be a cover in the
subposet of $W$ consisting of twisted involutions.

> Is $E_-(w)\big/ \left( E_-(w) \cap E_-(v) \right)$ always $1$-dimensional?

I have a nontrivial map from this space to $\mathbb Z$, so I know it's at least $1$-dimensional. I've computed it in a number of examples $(G,\theta)$ and could probably give an exhaustive proof, but of course I'd rather a well-motivated one.

EDIT: it's equivalent to ask if $(1+v\theta)(1-w\theta) = 1+(v-w)\theta-vw^{-1}$ has rank $1$. (Not that this has helped me.)

EDIT: Actually I don't care about *all* the twisted involutions -- only those in the image of $K\backslash G/B \to B\backslash G/B \cong W$, $g \mapsto \theta(g)^{-1} g$. (For example, in the $A_{odd}$ flipped case the image is fixed-point-free involutions.) It's harder to characterize the image than to give the definition of twisted involution, though, so I'm hoping the above is true in general.

Comment: If $w \theta$ is an involution of $T$, don't we get $\theta w \theta = w^{-1}$? Is the dot meant to denote conjugation?

Comment: Yes, dot for conjugation.

Comment: With the $A_3$ Dynkin diagram and the non-trivial involution $\theta$ on it, the Weyl group is $\mathfrak{S_4}$ generated by $(12), (23), (34)$. In this case $\theta\cdot(12) = (34)$, $\theta\cdot(34) = (12)$ and $\theta\cdot(23) = (23)$. Don't you have $(12)(34) > e$ as a cover in the subset of twisted involution?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. In this case both $E_{-}(e)$ and $E_{-}((12)(34))$ are of dimension $2$ and their intersection is of dimension $1$.